# Purple Button in Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, bootstrap-5

thanks for reading. I'm new to React but I'm building a web app with React.js and ASP.NET Core. I'm using the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

export class Counter extends Component {
static displayName = Counter.name;

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = { currentCount: 0 };
}

render() {
return (
  <div>
     <h1>Patient Survey</h1>
     <p>Please click the button below to get started</p>
     <ul>
         <button type="button" color="primary" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Go to Survey</button>
     </ul>
  </div>
);
}
}
```

to render a page that looks like the included photo.
[image]

Is there anyway I can make the button purple instead of green? I downloaded bootstrap to my project through npm, but I can't find anywhere on the website how to change the buttons from their standard colors like "danger" and "success" to something individual like purple.

Let me know if I can include any more code to help figure this out! Thanks!

Comment: You would want to use this `<Button />` not this `<button ></button>` as you have imported `import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';`

Comment: when I use the capital B's, my page renders as blank. any idea why?

Comment: Actually you should import `Button` without including `{}` like this `import Button  from 'react-bootstrap'` so then it work properly because it is default component exported by `react-bootstrap` and if it is an object then used  `{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a style attribute to the button.

```
<button 
    type="button" 
    color="primary" 
    class="btn btn-success btn-lg" 
    style={{ backgroundColor: 'purple' }}
>
```

Comment: this totally worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access to your class in the CSS file by adding the corresponding class in css.

For example:

```
className="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-purple"
```

Comment: You're totally right. I ended up combining your solution with one above it. I changed "btn-primary" default background color to the hex code for the color I wanted in the custom.css file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can set the color a few different ways.  A simple approach would be to add a style attribute to the `button` tag.

```js
<Button type="button" color="primary" style={{ backgroundColor: 'purple' }} className="btn btn-success btn-lg">Go to Survey</Button>
```

The style tag allows you to pass an object with several different css style.  In this example we are changing the background color to 'purple'.

Colors can be represented many different ways hex, rgb, names, etc.  A good reference for colors is [MDN Colors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color)

Bootstrap might provide a predefined class for purple backgrounds, this I am not sure of.

You can always define your own css class as well.

```css
.purple-button {
  background-color: 'purple';
}
```

```js
<Button type="button" color="primary" className="btn btn-success btn-lg purple-button">Go to Survey</Button>
```

Comment: thank you so much! I did the style one and it totally worked